# Deploying .exe from console application using EF & Oracle failed

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I'm trying to deploy my console application which mainly creates xml files from oracle tables. When I'm running the app on my machine (Windows 7 64-bit) through Visual Studio 2012, there is no problem.

My app is meant to run on a server which is using Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit. So, I copied the .exe, the config file, the Entity Framework dll and the config file from the bin\Debug project folder.

When I'm running the .exe, I got that error message :

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration or is not valid

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: Did you try googling the error? This is the first search result I found http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/651764/The-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-th

Comment: I saw that post but I'm not working with SQLite...

Comment: I added "oracle" to the end of the search string do either of these help? It sounds like an ODAC problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137256/ef-with-oracle-the-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-the-configurat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596850/oracle-and-entity-framework-errorthe-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found If not I think more information may be needed

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was solved by targeting the Framework 4.0 instead of the 4.5 one (Right-Click on my project in the Solution Explorer, then properties to do that). Didn't know that my prod machine wasn't able to run 4.5 .NET app.